# Xamarin Forms Editor - Completed raised when the control gets unfocused

Tags: input, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on the last part of my studying project and I have to implement a chat functionality. I then began by realizing it from a new project (faster for testing to me). However, I am facing something, I don't know if it's a bug but there is the situation:

First, the problem comes from the input, there are two controls I will take as example:

- Entry
- Editor

I would like to use `Editor` for its multiline capability, it makes it more readable to me (Maybe it's possible from a simple Entry, but that's not the point I wanna focus on).

I can type my text, everything is good, but it's when I want to send this text that my problem is. In fact, it doesn't seem possible to have a submit button in the keyboard (I couldn't make it), so I created a button (which is gray, at the right of the input).

When I click that `Button`, you and me agree that we 'unfocus' the `Editor`, so `Unfocused` is raised and the method attached *`public void OnInputUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs fe) {}`* is called.

**So my question is: Why** `Completed` **is called too?**

I put the project on github: https://github.com/Emixam23/ChatAppExample

---

If you take a look at the `README` or just by scrolling down, you will see some information about it and how to try the two different behaviors between `Entry` and `Editor`

Thanks for any help!